# WordPress: use custom template for all posts in a given category

Tags: wordpress

It is not a problem to make a template for a single category archive or a post.

But I can't either google, find in Codex or figure out myself how to assign a custom template to all posts in a given category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with the following crutch.

Putted the following into functions.php to detect current post's top level parent category ID:

```
function get_top_level_cat_id ($catid) {
while ($catid) {
$cat = get_category($catid);
$catid = $cat->category_parent;
$catParent = $cat->cat_ID;
}
return $catParent;
}
```

Then copied current single.php into _single.php and replaced all single.php content with:

```
<?php
// functions.php !!!
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$catid = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$top_level_cat_id = get_top_level_cat_id ($catid);

if ($top_level_cat_id == XX) {require __DIR__ . '/_single_XXX.php';}
elseif ($top_level_cat_id == YY) {require __DIR__ . '/_single_YYY.php';}
else {require __DIR__ . '/_single.php';}
?>
```

So now I can copy _single.php into _single_XXX.php and edit it whatever I like. The same is for _single_YYY.php, _single_ZZZ.php, etc.

**I'm still not satisfied with such solution and would appreciate any better suggestion.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use find this information on the [WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org) website.

This is what I found when doing a quick [Google Search](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

Basically you have these Template Files (these are also in order of what WordPress will look for first) :

1) `category-slug.php`
2) `category-ID.php`
3) `category.php`

Comment: Those will add custom templates for particular categories pages, while I'm looking for a method of assigning a single template file **for all posts** within a given category, even without touching the category page itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use in single.php this code to switch templates like so:

```
 if ( in_category('fruit') ) {
         include 'single-fruit.php';
     } elseif ( in_category('vegetables') ) {
         include 'single-vegetables.php';
     } else {
         // Continu enter code here with normal Loop
         if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
         // ...
     }
```